# What input does the Exchange get-mailbox command accept?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, ems

Please bear with me if this question sounds too stupid..  but I am very confused as what does the Exchange get-mailbox command accepts as the identity input.  According to Microsoft's documentation, (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998579(v=exchg.80).aspx) the identity parameter can either be alias, smtp or display name, which makes perfect sense.

However, I have a teamate, in a different office, can use the SamAccountName of accounts as the identity input to the get-mailbox command!! The SamAccountName does not resemble none of the alias, smtp, nor the display name.... and this really confuses me.  My teamate has no clue why that works for him too.

Does anyone have a good understanding of how does the get-mailbox works to retrieve the information?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that Exchange (@ least from version 2003) resolve `sAMAccountName` to mailbox `recipient name` like it does in the `to:` field in a new email from Outlook in a domain environment, but I can't find an official document from microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for the `-Identity` parameter here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123685.aspx